# Стилизация элементов iframe тега приложения Trustpilot

Tags: javascript, iframe, observer, shopify

В shopify,

У меня на сайте используется виджет отзывов Trustpilot, который использует тег `iframe`. И мне нужно стилизовать некоторые внутренние элементы. Я делаю это через javascript, используя `observer`, потому как виджет необходимо дожидаться.

Для тестирования я просто задаю красный фон для тега `body` внутри `iframe`, и этот стиль применяется буквально на 1 секунду, и после, стиль пропадает. Так же, я смотрел стили в DOM, но моих стилей нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему это происходит, и как это исправить? Вот код:

```
let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    let widget_iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    if (widget_iframe) {
        let style = document.createElement("style");
        style.textContent = 'body: { background: red; }';
        widget_iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(style);
        observer.disconnect();
    }
});
observer.observe(document.body, { attributes: true, attributeFilter: ["style"], childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: На сколько я помню, изменить стили через iframe не получится, т.к. iframe просто отображает другой сайт. Вот тут более подробнее про коммуникацию [между окнами](https://learn.javascript.ru/cross-window-communication)

Comment: да, согласен. iframe действительно из другого источника. Спасибо, за ответ.

Comment: @SwaD, я так же пробовал это решение, но не помогло - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667750/customizing-the-js-css-in-a-trustpilot-widget